# What is an EVM externality?

Tags: evm, openethereum, rust

While reading the [OpenEthereum codebase](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum), I encountered [this type](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/blob/f1dc6821689c7f47d8fd07dfc0a2c5ad557b98ec/crates/vm/vm/src/ext.rs#L67):

```rust
/// Externalities interface for EVMs
pub trait Ext {
    /// Returns the storage value for a given key if reversion happens on the current transaction.
    fn initial_storage_at(&self, key: &H256) -> Result<H256>;

    /// Returns a value for given key.
    fn storage_at(&self, key: &H256) -> Result<H256>;

    /// Stores a value for given key.
    fn set_storage(&mut self, key: H256, value: H256) -> Result<()>;

    /* more code... */
```

The reason it's significant is that, in order to execute EVM bytecode, the `Interpreter` trait specifies a parameter of this type that needs to be passed into the [`step` function](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/blob/f1dc6821689c7f47d8fd07dfc0a2c5ad557b98ec/crates/vm/evm/src/interpreter/mod.rs#L333):

```rust
/// Execute a single step on the VM.
    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn step(&mut self, ext: &mut dyn vm::Ext) -> InterpreterResult {
        /* more code... */
```

The best I can come up with is that the `Ext` type abstracts away external blockchain state so that a given instance of the EVM can be given its own context?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! In case you don't get an answer, you'll probably get at https://discord.io/openethereum and please post back here :)